# two SKScene Objects with separated View orientation

Tags: uiviewcontroller, orientation, sprite-kit, skscene, skview

I assumed would have two SKScene objects. The first SKScene should only support the portrait view and the second SKScene should only support the Landscape view and are actually started by the first SKScene. Can this be so implemented, or does it only with two ViewControllers.

Regards SKNode

Comment: I'm afraid you have to add a separate `ViewController` for that. Device orientation is handling on `ViewController` layer

Comment: ok thank you. 
I already feared.